# Javascript Class Object - Same values Multiple names

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, variables, object

I want to create multiple object using a class for example:

```
function _Class(_number) {
     this.numer = _number;
    }
```

and i want to make 36 objects with the same attributes but different values. I stuck almost on beggining because i used loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
name="number_"+i;    
var name=new _Class(i); 
}
```

and after this code i can't acces to any object. Is there a way that I can create a variable which name is value of array ?

All code:

```
//test 
function test(x){
    for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        document.write(x);
    }
}
var pola = [0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26, 0];
var nazwy_obiektow = new Array(100);
for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
    nazwy_obiektow[i] = "liczba_" + i;
}
function _Klasa_Liczb() {
     this.numer = 1;
    }
for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
    var nazwy_obiektow[i]=new _Klasa_Liczb; 
}
test(liczba_0);
```

Comment: Create the variable outside of the loop. To initialize it to an array, the most concise way is like: var myArray = [];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array.

```
function _Class(_number) {
        this.numer = _number;
 }
 var objects = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
    name = "number_" + i;
    objects[i] = new _Class(name);
 }
```

Then you can see each object in the array (`objects[0]`, `objects[1]`,...).

Comment: Done this and I can't acces to the values of object outside the code.

Comment: Where is your var objects? Think that the scope of your variables is the function which was declared. Define your objects outside of functions.

Comment: @Czcibor if you think this is a right answer to your question, you should mark it as "Answer" so other users know it helped you.